# Using text() to match custom entity names in XSLT

Tags: php, xslt, xml-entities

I am using `<xsl:template match="m:*/text()">` to match text in my XML Document, which is working fine for plain text and known entities, i.e. it works fine for entities like `&amp;` or unicode entities like `&#x003C0;`.

However what's not working is matching custom entity names. For example I have an entity `&pi;` in my XML Document, that should be matched using `text()`. For some reason it does not treat that entity as text, meaning nothing is being matched.

Please note that I did declare the entity name in the Doctype declaration of the XML Document, and of the XSLT Document as well:

`<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY pi "&#x003C0;">]>`

Is `text()` the right approach to matching custom entity names, or do I need to use another function? (Maybe I also did something wrong declaring the entity name?)

Thanks

***Edit***

**XML**

```
<!DOCTYPE mathml [<!ENTITY pi "&#x003C0;">]>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="inline">    
    <mi>&pi;</mi>
    <mi>test</mi>
    <mi>&#x003C0;</mi>
</math>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY pi "&#x003C0;">]>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
                version='1.0'>

    <xsl:template match="m:*/text()">
        <xsl:call-template name="replaceEntities">
            <xsl:with-param name="content" select="normalize-space()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="replaceEntities">
        <xsl:param name="content"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$content"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The variable `$content` should get printed three times, however only `test` and `&#x003C0;` is printed.

**Processing using PHP**

```
$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc->load("doc.xsl");
$xslProcessor = new \XSLTProcessor();
$xslProcessor->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
$mathMLDoc = new DOMDocument();
$mathMLDoc->loadXML('<!DOCTYPE mathml [<!ENTITY pi "&#x003C0;">]><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="inline"><mi>&pi;</mi><mi>test</mi><mi>&#x003C0;</mi></math>');
echo $xslProcessor->transformToXML($mathMLDoc);
```

Comment: Just a guess here, but could it be that the XML parser parsing your XSLT swaps the `&pi` with `&#x003C0` and that's why `text()` won't match it?

Comment: Please show a complete, minimal and verifiable sample of both your input XML and your XSLT stylesheet: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, since it does match it if I replace `&pi;` in the XML document with `&#x003C0;`. So even if it would be swapped, `text()` should still be able to match it. @MathiasMüller I will

Comment: and explain how you are parsing the XML and invoking the stylesheet - `text()` should match _any_ text node, so your issue is probably something specific to the way you're invoking the transformation rather than anything wrong with the transformation itself.

Comment: Interesting, the output from Saxon 9.5 is `πtestπ`, using the PHP code it's `testπ`.

Comment: That is indeed interesting. I wonder if there is a way to get the right output using PHP's XSLTProcessor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem is that the DTD is not visible to the XSLT stylesheet. Use the following to substitute entities with their textual value before transforming the document:

```
$mathMLDoc->substituteEntities = true;
```

as in

```
$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc->load("tree.xsl");
$xslProcessor = new \XSLTProcessor();
$xslProcessor->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
$mathMLDoc = new DOMDocument();
$mathMLDoc->substituteEntities = true;
$mathMLDoc->loadXML('<!DOCTYPE math [<!ENTITY pi "&#x003C0;">]><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="inline"><mi>&pi;</mi><mi>test</mi><mi>&#x003C0;</mi></math>');
echo $xslProcessor->transformToXML($mathMLDoc);
```

which will produce

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
πtestπ
```

---

Some background: http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php#99932 and http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001854.html.